# iOS app on iPhone Simulator error: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErreurDomain

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to run my iOS app using MacOS 11.1 and Xcode 12.2 using iPhone Simulator,  I'm getting the following error :

```
FBSOpenApplicationServiceErreurDomain code:5 and 
BSServiceConnectionErreurDomaim code:3
```

I already tried to quit Xcode, clean project, etc. Any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

[image: this is a snapshot of my error]